# Call Python script from php with exec()

Tags: php, python

I have one python script for handling outlook emails using Outlook MAPI. I have to call this script from PHP code. If I call script from cmd it is fine, but when I do it from PHP doesn't work and there are no errors. Also if I just call some other python script with simple file writing code from same PHP script it works. I have no idea what to do. I am trying with `exec('python c:/xampp/SCRIPT_LOCATION/SCRIPT.py')` as well as shell_exec(), system()... but with no progression.

Comment: Does the user account used to run PHP have appropriate execute permissions on the file?

Comment: Capture `stderr`, or check the log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$python = 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe';
$pyscript = 'C:\\xampp\\SCRIPT_LOCATION\\SCRIPT.py';

exec("$python $pyscript");
```

Comment: Tried many times but doesn't work.When I did echo exec('whoami'); I got nt authority\system. But I don't thing so that this is important. Because recently PHP call to python scripts worked.